# Nest js prefix changing issue for routes

Tags: controller, prefix, nestjs

I tried to change change the prefix for route in the controller in nest js. Previously my route was items . I changed it to api/items but still it remains items .

Expected : @Controller('api/items')

Got : items only.

**I am using concurrently to run Nest and Angular together**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this on my project and it works. Check if you have any routes prefixes defined where you start the nest application. Or any rule that will mess with your routes.

[image][image]

Make sure you are building your app. 
Also, if you want to make all the routes have '/api/' you can do that like this:

```
 const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);

 app.setGlobalPrefix(prefix)
```

where prefix can be anything you want.

Comment: Even adding setGlobalPrefix('api') doesn't work.
What ever route was added in the beginning, nest only retains that route.. changing it later doesn't work !!
Not sure what the issue is

Comment: Longshot here, but how are you starting your application? Are you making sure it's re-compiled? I know it's a silly question, but the smallest things can slip through sometimes. It would help if we could see more code

Comment: I tried creating a new project and changing prefix worked like a charm. But once I used concurrently to run nest and angular together, it stopped working.When nest re-complies, the [RoutesResolver] always shows the old path. Is it an issue with concurrently ? Even if I serve only the nest files, it doesn't work after that.

Comment: Maybe it s possible you are not compiling your app. This should be your first check. It should work. Can't be possible.